# AJAX-based navigation and Browser restore

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, browser-cache

I am using AJAX-based navigation in a section of a Rails website, using two basic jQuery hooks, expressed here in Coffescript:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'a.ajax_nav', (e) ->
  window.history.pushState(null, "page title", this.href)

$(window).on 'popstate', (e) ->
  $.getScript(document.location)
```

or the equivalent Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax_nav', function(e) {
  return window.history.pushState(null, "page title", this.href);
});
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
  return $.getScript(document.location);
});
```

The navigation works fine, I can use the browser's back/forward buttons, and do a page refresh, in which case, instead of executing a JS script, the action renders the corresponding full HTML view.

However, when I navigate to a page using AJAX (so partial content is loaded by executing a script), close the browser, then reopen it and choose the "restore tabs" option, the page displays the script code (but with the ERB bits rendered) instead of executing it. I am guessing this is because what was cached by the browser at the time of the request was the server response, which was that script exactly.

So my question is, is there a way to manipulate the browser cache to force it to reload the page, for instance by setting the response headers to a no-cache value when rendering a JS format request? Would that cause the browser to reload the page and thus fall back on the HTML render (which would be perfectly fine)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the following to my root application controller (application_controller.rb):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  .
  .
  before_filter :set_cache_for_js
  .
  .
  protected

    def set_cache_for_js
      set_cache_buster if request.format == 'text/javascript' # probably a better way to do this
    end

    def set_cache_buster
      response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
      response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    end
.
.
end
```

This way, the `set_cache_for_js` filter is called before every action throughout the application. If the requested format is javascript, then the headers are manipulated to 'bust' the cache, keeping the browser from caching the javascript response, and thus forcing a reload of the page based on the URL, which renders the document properly.